# How much coal does a Hobbyist Steam Engine use for a full tank of water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-railcraft

How much coal should I put in my Hobbyist Steam Engine so that the (full) tank of water and the coal run out at the same time?

Comment: How much coal could a Hobbyist Steam Engine use for a full tank of water if a Hobbyist Steam Engine could use coal for a full tank of water? A Hobbyist Steam Engine could use as much coal for a full tank of water as a Hobbyist Steam Engine could use for a full tank of water. So elegant.

Comment: What mods are you using?

Comment: @scienceguyz RailCraft - see the tags.

Comment: @fredley I understand, but certain mods (ie gregtech) modify OTHER mods. Railcraft may be modified by a different mod in whatever modpack he's using, or he could be using just simply railcraft.

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone has ever tried to answer this question before, for multiple reasons.  Hobbyist Steam Engines have a warmup period before they reach full speed, which could affect water and coal usage, causing the ratio to vary.  Also, most people who use this kind of engine have already built an infinite water source of sorts to keep the tank full, so it runs as long as it has coal.

Comment: If you're trying to micromanage your water supply you're probably making this more difficult than it needs to be. It isn't hard to get "infinite" water into your machines. If you're using buckets then you probably won't get them to run out simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

In FTB Infinity 1.2.1 (Railcraft 9.5.0.0) I ran two experiments running a Hobbyist Steam Engine out of a full tank of water:

- Starting Cold: **35** Coal
- Staring at 500 degrees C: **33** Coal

There are many things which can affect what you are talking about.  The exact release of a mod, other mods as well as modpack configs.  Many packs balance power generation so multiple ways of generating power are balanced against each other.

Your best bet is to load up a creative test world and create the conditions you are looking for.  That way you can control your own variables like whether or not the engine is cold, whether you will consume 100% of the power generated once the engine's buffer fills up, etc. This is what I did to get the results above.

Comment: This would work better as a comment than as an answer, since you're talking about how to reach the answer rather than giving an answer. (I realize it's a bit long for a comment, but I think you can make it fit.) Welcome to Arquade!

Comment: I don't have the reputation to answer, and didn't realize giving someone the knowledge to reach the answer was inappropriate as an answer.  Sort of a catch-22.  I can't ask them the detail I need to answer their question, and i can't pose that question any other way.  Unless I'm expected to use a private message?

Comment: I meant i didn't have the rep to comment.  But I'm revising my answer to a more precise answer anyway.

Comment: you *can* give "how to do this" as an answer, but the trouble is that Arquade is trying to be a repository of knowledge, not just a bunch of forum threads where individual askers get answers. If every single person who visits this question has to go off and do their own research based on your answer, then this isn't a great answer and won't collect much/any upvotes. Now, it's a really great answer that everyone can learn from; thanks for researching and editing! +1